# Rails 3 - ActiveRecord, what is more efficient (update vs. count)?

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

Okay, lets say I got 2 different Models:

1. **Poll** (has_many :votes)
2. **Vote** (belongs_to :poll)

So, one poll can have many votes.
At the moment I'm displaying a list of all polls including its overall vote_count.

---

Everytime someone votes for a poll, I'm going to update the overall vote_count of the specific poll by using:

`@poll = Poll.update(params[:poll_id], :vote_count => vote_count+1)`
To retrieve the vote_count I use : `@poll.vote_count` which works fine. 
 
Lets assume I got a huge amount of polls (in my db) and a lot of people would vote for the same poll at the same time.

---

**Question :**
 Wouldn't it be more efficient to remove the vote_count from the poll table and use: 
`@vote_count = Poll.find(params[:poll_id]).votes.count` 
for retrieving the overall **vote_count** instead? 
Which operation (update vs. count) would make more sense in this case?
(I'm using postgresql in production)

*Thanks for the help!*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails counter cache vs calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232841/rails-counter-cache-vs-calculation)

Comment: It's not exactly the same as your question, because it specifically states counter caches (which is something you've implemented yourself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using a [counter cache (see counter_cache option)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)? Rails has this built in functionality to handle all the possible updates to an association and how that would affect the counter.

It's as simple as adding a 0 initialized integer column named `#{attribute.pluralize}_count`(in your case `votes_count`) on the table of one to many side of an association (in your case Poll).

And then on the other side of the association add the `:counter_cache => true` argument to the belongs to statement.

```
belongs_to :poll, :counter_cache => true
```

Now this doesn't answer your question exactly, and the correct answer will depend on the shape of your data and the indexes you've configured. If you're expecting your votes table to number in the millions spread out over thousands of polls, then go with the counter cache, otherwise just counting the associations should be fine.

Comment: that's cool.  how does it deal with the attribute being null, do those get counted?

Comment: It should be an integer columns should be initialized to zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the counter_cache thing seems right for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question as it touches the fundamental issue of storing summary and aggregate information.

Generally this is not a good idea as things can easily get out of sync as systems grow.

Sometimes there are occasions when you do want summary information, but these are more specialized cases such as read-open databases that are only used for reporting and are updated once a day at midnight.
In those cases summary aggregate reporting is not only ok but is preferred over repeated summary/aggregate information calculation that would otherwise be done with each query.  That will also depend on both usage and size, e.g. if there are 300 queries a day (against the once a day updated, read only database) and they all have to calculate the same totals, and each query reads 20,000 rows, it is more efficient to do that once and store that calculation.  As the data and queries grow this may be the only practical way to allow complex reporting.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it doesn't make more sense in such a simple case to use a vote_count in the Poll. Counting rows is really fast and if you add a vote and forget to increment vote_count then the data is kind of broken...

Comment: You're totally right about the 'forget to increment' thing, but I'm not really sure yet, if the counting is fast enough in my case (let assume I have like 1.000.000+ votes in my database)